# nw_resolver_start_query_timer_block_invoke [C12] Query fired: did not receive all answers in time for

Tags: swift, swift5, ios15

why i receive thi error message?

"nw_resolver_start_query_timer_block_invoke [C12] Query fired: did not receive all answers in time for "